# Relative point distance to sign

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have two points in space that can move along the $X$ axis. In their initial position, its easy to know if one of them is behind the other, for example:

$A=(-1, 0, 0)$

$B=(1, 0, 0)$

So if $x$ coordinate of $A$ is less than $B$ one, I could say, according to my problem, that $A$ is in the "negative" direction from $B$.

The problem is that I can move that points freely in space, maintaining its relative position. So the question is, how can I determine if $A$ is in negative direction from $B$ or vice versa?

I can determine the absolute position of $A$ and $B$ anytime.

To better understand my problem, suppose a car moving around with a rail on top of it, and attached to the rail there is a piece that can move along that rail. I want to know any given moment if the piece is in one side or the other of the rail, independently of the car orientation in space.

EDIT: Hopefully behind and negative concepts in my explanation are less ambiguous now.

EDIT2: Gave an example to explain my problem better.

Comment: What's your definition of behind? Because you could argue that $A$ was infront of $B$ in your example along the x-axis

Comment: Sorry, maybe behind is ambiguous, lets say A<B if A_x<B_x, in that initial position.

Comment: If the piece is attached to the rail, why does the car matter?  You can find the slope of the rail, but you have to keep track of direction along the rail.  Say the rail runs from (0,0)  to (1,0), does a left U turn to (1,1) and runs back to (1,0).  If the piece is on the bottom segment, above the rail will be to the left.  If it is on the top segment, above the rail will be to the right.

Answer (score 0):

With your edit that $A \lt B$ if $A_x \lt B_x$, you can apply that test at any time.  You could also define that A is in the negative direction from B if $A_x \lt B_x, A_y \lt B_y, A_z \lt B_z$.  That only gives you a comparison $1/4$ of the time.  Suppose A and B represent cars on a road that makes a U turn upward.  After a while, if they move at the same speed you will have A at $(1,1,0)$, B at $(-1,1,0)$ and you might want to say B is still ahead of A.  You have to define much more clearly what you want.

Comment: I just wrote an example of my problem using a car. Sorry if I sound a bit confusing, but English is not my native language :(